# Google Page speed insights doesn't work with sites hosted on Firebase Hosting

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have built a website for a company and when I go to try the domain which is https://openroad.nz in google pagespeed, it returns with this error `Requests from referer https://www.googleapis.com/ are blocked`.

Any idea what and why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

works fine for me, you got 74 / 100, only thing I can think of is that you are using Brave Browser with 'Shields Up' or have a firewall in place that is blocking the request.

Try using Google Chrome in Incognito Mode while tethered to your mobile phone (as that eliminates most possible blocks) and see if that allows you to run the test.

Comment: Funny enough I am using the Brave browser, why does it not allow me to do it on the Brave browser?

Comment: Shields Up blocks certain requests, cookies etc. I think it has something to do with an authentication header the API is expecting that is blocked by Brave.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Brave browser, which I am and ran into this issue because of it, you'll need to enable advanced view for Brave Shield settings (the lion logo to the right of the address bar:

[image: Image enabling advanced settings for Brave Shield settings]

and then change the cookie settings to "All Cookies Allowed" PageSpeed Insights will work.

[image: Image enabling all cookies allowed in Brave Shield settings]